# get First 10 result in MongoDB collection

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to get First top 10 result in MongoDb Query

For that I tried something like this

```
return _users.Collection.FindAll().Limit(10).ToList();
```

But this is not working then I tried following thing according to most of resources, but this one also not working

```
return _users.Collection.Aggregate([{ "$limit": 10 }]).ToList();
```

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: @w0lf syntax errors occurring :(

Comment: post the errors, as that may be crucial in finding the cause and suggesting a solution

Comment: for 2nd one `There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'args' of 'MongoCollection.Aggregate(AggregateArgs)' `

Comment: also, you may want to specify C# (or whatever language you are using) as a tag

Comment: I added it for you. You have to edit the question and add the appropriate tags in the Tags section.

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
return _users.Collection.Find(x => true).Limit(10).ToList();
```

Instead of FindAll()

Answer (score 3):

- `find({})` will find all the documents and `limit()` will filter your results.

  ```
   return _users.Collection.find({}).limit(10).ToList();
  ```